# Определение слов в строке с условием

Tags: python

Есть строка, нужно определить в ней те слова, которые начинаются и оканчиваются на одну и ту же букву.

Подскажите как быть.

Comment: Разбить строку на слова, и проверять первую и последнюю букву каждого слова, наверное. Доступ к отдельным буквам в слове можно получить так же как вы обращаетесь к элементам списка.

Comment: s=input()
q=s.split(' ')
for k in q:
 if k[0]==k[-1]:
  print(k)

Comment: все отлично, спасибо большое! не знал о такой функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '...'
words = [i for i in s.split() if i[0] == i[-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
words = your_string.split() # Разбиваем строку по пробелам на слова
answer_words = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == x[-1], words))
# Фильтруем от слов, у которых последний (-1) символ отличается от первого (0)
```